# How to prevent multi threaded application to read this same Sql Server record twice

Tags: sql-server, multithreading

I am working on a system that uses multiple threads to read, process and then update database records. Threads run in parallel and try to pick records by calling Sql Server stored procedure.

They call this stored procedure looking for unprocessed records multiple times per second and sometimes pick this same record up.

I try to prevent this happening this way:

```
UPDATE  dbo.GameData
SET     Exported = @Now,
        ExportExpires = @Expire,
        ExportSession = @ExportSession
OUTPUT  Inserted.ID INTO @ExportedIDs
WHERE ID IN (   SELECT TOP(@ArraySize) GD.ID 
                FROM        dbo.GameData GD 
                WHERE       GD.Exported IS NULL 
                ORDER BY    GD.ID ASC)
```

The idea here is to set a record as exported first using an UPDATE with OUTPUT (remembering record id), so no other thread can pick it up again. When record is set as exported, then I can do some extra calculations and pass the data to the external system hoping that no other thread will pick this same record again in the mean time. Since the UPDATE that has in mind to secure the record first.

Unfortunately it doesn't seem to be working and the application sometimes pick same record twice anyway.

How to prevent it?

Kind regards
Mariusz

Comment: Perhaps wrap it in a transaction with Serializable isolation level?

Comment: Thank you. I found a SO post explaining how to use SERIALIZABLE but it seems like it only prevents updates and deletes. For me it's important to block other threads from reading this same record also. Although I will test it first to check, as it's highest restriction, so if this doesn't work no other restriction will perhaps either.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3467613/isolation-level-serializable-when-should-i-use-this

Comment: I am not sure about your exact requirement, but once I fall in this situation I used a simple locker object to allow only one thread in my working function to enter.

Comment: Thanks M Idrees. I have rather multiple instances of an application running this same time and they don't communicate between each other.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should be able to do this atomically using a common table expression. (I'm not 100% certain about this, and I haven't tested, so you'll need to verify that it works for you in your situation.)

```
;WITH cte AS
(
    SELECT TOP(@ArrayCount)
        ID, Exported, ExportExpires, ExportSession
    FROM dbo.GameData WITH (READPAST)
    WHERE Exported IS NULL
    ORDER BY ID
)
UPDATE cte
SET Exported = @Now,
    ExportExpires = @Expire,
    ExportSession = @ExportSession
OUTPUT INSERTED.ID INTO @ExportedIDs
```

Comment: This should be guaranteed to work because updates take U-locks on the rows being affected and the clustered index is always locked first.

Comment: Thank you very much for help. I will use this approach.

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar set up and I use [`sp_getapplock`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189823.aspx). My application runs many threads and they call a stored procedure to get the `ID` of the element that has to be processed. `sp_getapplock` guarantees that the same `ID` would not be chosen by two different threads.

I have a `MyTable` with a list of `IDs` that my application checks in an infinite loop using many threads. For each `ID` there are two `datetime` columns: `LastCheckStarted` and `LastCheckCompleted`. They are used to determine which `ID` to pick. Stored procedure picks an `ID` that wasn't checked for the longest period. There is also a hard-coded period of 20 minutes - the same `ID` can't be checked more often than every 20 minutes.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetNextIDToCheck]
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    BEGIN TRANSACTION;
    BEGIN TRY

        DECLARE @VarID int = NULL;

        DECLARE @VarLockResult int;
        EXEC @VarLockResult = sp_getapplock
            @Resource = 'SomeUniqueName_app_lock',
            @LockMode = 'Exclusive',
            @LockOwner = 'Transaction',
            @LockTimeout = 60000,
            @DbPrincipal = 'public';

        IF @VarLockResult >= 0
        BEGIN
            -- Acquired the lock
            -- Find ID that wasn't checked for the longest period
            SELECT TOP 1
                @VarID = ID
            FROM
                dbo.MyTable
            WHERE
                LastCheckStarted <= LastCheckCompleted
                -- this ID is not being checked right now
                AND LastCheckCompleted < DATEADD(minute, -20, GETDATE())
                -- last check was done more than 20 minutes ago
            ORDER BY LastCheckCompleted;

            -- Start checking
            UPDATE dbo.MyTable
            SET LastCheckStarted = GETDATE()
            WHERE ID = @VarID;
            -- There is no need to explicitly verify if we found anything.
            -- If @VarID is null, no rows will be updated
        END;

        -- Return found ID, or no rows if nothing was found, 
        -- or failed to acquire the lock
        SELECT
            @VarID AS ID
        WHERE
            @VarID IS NOT NULL
        ;

        COMMIT TRANSACTION;
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
    END CATCH;

END
```

The second procedure is called by an application when it finishes checking the found `ID`.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[SetCheckComplete]
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @ParamID int
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    BEGIN TRANSACTION;
    BEGIN TRY

        DECLARE @VarLockResult int;
        EXEC @VarLockResult = sp_getapplock
            @Resource = 'SomeUniqueName_app_lock',
            @LockMode = 'Exclusive',
            @LockOwner = 'Transaction',
            @LockTimeout = 60000,
            @DbPrincipal = 'public';

        IF @VarLockResult >= 0
        BEGIN
            -- Acquired the lock
            -- Completed checking the given ID
            UPDATE dbo.MyTable
            SET LastCheckCompleted = GETDATE()
            WHERE ID = @ParamID;
        END;

        COMMIT TRANSACTION;
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
    END CATCH;

END
```

Answer (score 0):

It does not work because multiple transactions might first execute the IN clause and find the same set of rows, then update multiple times and overwrite each other.

LukeH's answer is best, accept it.

You can also fix it by adding `AND Exported IS NULL` to cancel double updates.

Or, make this `SERIALIZABLE`. This will lead to some blocking and deadlocking. This can safely be handled by timeouts and retry in case of deadlock. `SERIALIZABLE` is **always** safe for all workloads but it might block/deadlock more often.

Comment: For a moment I was thinking about IN clause as well and that it may be the reason. Cheers for pointing it out. SERIALIZABLE seemed like quite a brutal solution :-)